# Django no está mostrando la url correcta al redirigir después de click en enlace

Tags: python, django, django-urls

**- Esto es lo que me muestra al hacer click en el enlace**

> Page not found (404)
>
> Request Method: GET Request 
>   URL: http://localhost:8000/jobapplication/new/1
>
> Using the URLconf defined in careal.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> ^$ [name='landing-index']
>
> ^admin/
>
> ^accounts/
>
> ^taskmanager/
>
> ^login/$ [name='login']

---

- El problema es que no sé por qué está abriendo directamente http://localhost:8000/jobapplication/new/1, cuando debería ser http://localhost:8000/taskmanager/jobapplication/new/1

**Esto es lo que tengo en urls.py general**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from landingpage import views as landingpage_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', landingpage_views.index, name='landing-index'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'^taskmanager/', include('taskmanager.urls')),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
]
```

**Esto en urls.py dentro de la aplicación taskmanager**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from taskmanager.views import *

app_name = 'taskmanager'
urlpatterns = [
    # Task manager urls
    url(r'^$', JobApplicationIndex.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'jobapplication/add/(?P<jobpost_id>[0-9]+)/$', JobApplicationCreate.as_view(), name='jobapplication-add'),
    url(r'jobapplication/new/(?P<jobpost_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.JobApplicationAdd, name='jobapplication-new'),
    url(r'jobapplication/edit/(?P<jobpost_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.JobApplicationEdit, name='jobapplication-edit'),
    url(r'jobapplication/edit/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', JobApplicationUpdate.as_view(), name='jobapplication-edit'),
    url(r'^jobapplication/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', JobApplicationDetails.as_view(), name='jobapplication-detail'),

    # Company urls
    url(r'company/$', CompanyIndex.as_view(), name='company-index'),
    url(r'company/add/$', CompanyCreate.as_view(), name='company-add'),
    url(r'^company/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', CompanyDetails.as_view(), name='company-detail'),

    # Job Post urls
    url(r'jobpost/$', JobPostIndex.as_view(), name='jobpost-index'),
    url(r'^jobpost/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', JobPostDetails.as_view(), name='jobpost-detail'),

    # Statistics urls
    url(r'^kpi/$', views.kpi, name='kpi'),
]
```

**Y esto es lo que tengo en views.py en taskmanager, con respecto a jobapplication**

```
# Job Application views
class JobApplicationIndex(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'taskmanager/jobapplication_index.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return JobApplication.objects.filter(user=self.request.user.id).order_by('-created_at')


class JobApplicationCreate(CreateView):
    model = JobApplication
    fields = ['jobpost', 'sent_date', 'deadline', 'success_rate']

    def get_initial(self):
        jobpost = get_object_or_404(JobPost, id=self.kwargs.get('jobpost_id'))
        return {
            'jobpost':jobpost,
        }

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(JobApplicationCreate, self).form_valid(form)

class JobApplicationDetails(generic.DetailView):
    model = JobApplication

class JobApplicationEdit(UpdateView):
    model = JobApplication
    #fields = ['jobpostid', 'is_favorite']
    #p = JobApplication.objects.get(id=jobpostid)
    #p.is_favorite = is_favorite
    #p.save()


class JobApplicationUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = JobApplication
    fields = ['sent_date', 'deadline', 'success_rate']
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'


def JobApplicationAdd(request, jobpost_id):
    if request.method == 'GET' and request.user.is_authenticated:
        # If job app for this id exists, redirect to that job app page with a message
        if JobApplication.objects.filter(jobpost_id=int(jobpost_id)).exists():
            existing = JobApplication.objects.get(jobpost_id=int(jobpost_id))
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'An application for this opening already exists.')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('taskmanager:jobapplication-detail', args=[existing.id]))

        jobapp = JobApplication(user=request.user, jobpost_id=int(jobpost_id), success_rate=50)
        jobapp.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('taskmanager:index'))
```

--- **La cosa es que todos los demás enlaces dentro de taskmanager funcionan, se abren con la url completa**
Ej: 
       -

```
      - http://localhost:8000/taskmanager/jobpost/
      - http://localhost:8000/taskmanager/jobpost/2/
      - http://localhost:8000/taskmanager/company/2/
      - http://localhost:8000/taskmanager/kpi/
```